# Activiti 6 App + Weblogic 12 = "ServletContext must not be null"

Tags: java, weblogic, activiti

I am trying to deploy Activiti 6 activiti-app.war file to Weblogic 12, and I am getting the following exception when trying to hit the login page:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ServletContext must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.findWebApplicationContext(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:305)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:250)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

This is my weblogic.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.5/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.2</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.joda.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Any Idea how to fix that

Comment: Did you try to add the spring context listener on web.xml?

Comment: Already activiti is using one that extends the spring context listener called WebConfigurer, when tried to add spring listener, I got an error saying that I have multiple listeners and only one is allowed

Comment: It seems like a classloading problem. Do you have spring libs in a shared lib or something thing like that ?

Comment: Another option is to use spring's webcontext listener and configure spring from there, since it looks you're using MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the webservletcontext object in DelegatingFilterProxy constructor in WebConfigurer Servlet Context Listener worked for me.

Existing code snippet in initSpringSecurity method is like below

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSecurityFilter = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
```

It worked after modifying the addFilter call like below:

```
WebApplicationContext webAppContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);

FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSecurityFilter = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain",webAppContext));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error

> No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

when invoking method WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext, try instantiating the WebContext like this:

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webAppContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webAppContext.register(ResourceWebConfig.class);
```

where the ResourceWebConfig class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ResourceWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```